# Why datetime is not apply to the parameter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a application runs this T-SQL command:

```
exec sp_executesql @statement = N'mysp @timestamp=0',
                   @params = N'@0 datetime',
                   @0 = '2021-04-08 20:59:10.987'
```

I log the `timestamp` value and I get empty for some reason:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

This is the stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mysp]
    @TimeStamp DATETIME = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE 
        ....
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @TimeStamp
        ...
```

What is wrong in the T-SQL command? How should it be in this structure?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code looks very product specific.)

Comment: the database is mssql

Comment: Should be  `@timestamp=@0` I guess.

Comment: @Serg yes it was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see is procedure named `mysp` which expects one parameter named `@timestamp`. The `=0` part sets the value of this parameter to `0`. It is **not** the name of another paramter. When interpreted as a datetime, a `0` value matches the `1900-01-01` you observed.

I expect this is what the application is trying to do:

```
exec sp_executesql @statement = N'mysp @timestamp',
                   @params = N'@timestamp datetime',
                   @timestamp = '2021-04-08 20:59:10.987'
```

Alternatively:

```
exec sp_executesql @statement = N'mysp @timestamp=@0',
                   @params = N'@0 datetime',
                   @0 = '2021-04-08 20:59:10.987'
```

In communicating with developers about how to fix this on their end, keep in mind they are probably not writing the `exec sp_executesql` code directly. Rather, they are more likely using a tool to just call `mysp` that alters the code to use `sp_executesql` behind the scenes for them. This is common practice as a safe way for developers to use parameterized queries in their code and avoid Sql Injection security issues.